# if-statement and try-catch doesn't prevent error

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

this part of my code should do the following:

1. Check if input is a int-type (try-catch)
2. if input is a int, check if it is in between the list:

Code

```
 public static void selection(List<Performer> listperformer)
 {
  int i=0;
  List<Performer> idlist = new ArrayList<Performer>();
  Scanner sclocal = new Scanner(System.in);

  if(listperformer.isEmpty() == true)
  {
   System.out.println("- empty -");
   return; 
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("Enter IDs:");
   int id;
   id=sclocal.nextInt();

   while(sclocal.hasNext())
   {

    try{
     id=sclocal.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException exception)
    {
     System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }

    if(listperformer.size() <= id || id < 0)
    {
     System.out.println("Invalid input! 294");
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     idlist.add(listperformer.get(id));
    }
    id=sclocal.nextInt();
   }
  }
```

doesn't work. Problem:
    1.

1. if i put in a wrong ID he asks me to put in another and after this
   throws an exception
2. if i put in a string throws an "InputMismatchException"

Let's assume, that there are only three entries in our list.
Results:

```
Input: 5
Output: 

Input: 4
Output: Invalid input! 294

Input: asdf
Output: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException...
```

Comment: Your observed "problematic" use-case works exactly as-intended, or to better say - as it was coded and as was expected.

Comment: To better understand what your code is doing, use the debugger almost certainly built into your IDE (or a standalone debugger) and walk through the code step-by-step. Using a debugger is an essential, not optional, part of learning to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reorganized a few of the lines, added some comments in the code, and also changed your System.out statements to reflect what is actually happening. In your catch block, the "sclocal.nextLine()" will consume the invalid input that caused the exception in the first place so that control can move forward to the next iteration.

As a general guideline, it would be a good idea to use "camelCase" for your variable names.

```
public static void selection(List<Performer> listperformer) {
    int i = 0;
    List<Performer> idlist = new ArrayList<Performer>();
    Scanner sclocal = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (listperformer.isEmpty() == true) {
        System.out.println("- empty -");
        return;
    } else {
        int id;//This is being used as an offset, so I recommend you rename it to "offset"
        System.out.println("Enter ID:");

        while (sclocal.hasNext()) {
            try {
                id = sclocal.nextInt();
                if (listperformer.size() <= id || id < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input! You requested the element at offset [" + id + "], but the max offset available is [" + (listperformer.size()-1) + "]. Exiting.");
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Input is valid. We have added the offset identifier [" + id + "] to listperformer.");
                    idlist.add(listperformer.get(id));
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                sclocal.nextLine();//throw away the invalid input so that we can await for the next input
            }
            System.out.println("Enter ID:");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, add all the missing information, could you please check it once again?

Comment: I re-arranged your code a little bit and added some comments to get things working. There's another comment in this thread about Exception handing, so I've added in a line of code there that you'll need to get the whole thing working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here.

1. The first is that in the first catch you only print an a message to System.out after this your programm will continue to run normally and thus goes to the next `id=sclocal.nextInt()`. Instead you should probably leave the function in your catch clause.
2. Now after your try-catch block you call `id=sclocal.nextInt()` again. This time without catching a possible exception while taking a completely new value from sclocal.You can fix this be removing that call and moving the if-else clause into your try block.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you probably want something more like this

```
while(true){
    try{
        id=sclocal.nextInt();
        if(listperformer.size() <= id || id < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! 294");
        }
        else {
            idlist.add(listperformer.get(id));
            break;
        }
    } catch(InputMismatchException exception) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, leads to a endless output of:"Invalid input! 294"

Answer (score 0):

You need to include *all* the code that depends on the exception throwing operation in the try-catch block. I extended your code to an MWE (see output below).

```
import java.util.*;

public class TryCatch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sclocal = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> listperformer = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        List<Integer> idlist = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            int id=sclocal.nextInt();
            if(listperformer.size() <= id || id < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! 294");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                idlist.add(listperformer.get(id));
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
Input: string
Output: Invalid input!

Input: 1
Output: [2]

Input: 5
Output: Invalid input! 294
```